# How do I register a marker interface so it is visible in Plones's ZMI?

Tags: plone, zope

I would like to register a marker interface so I can add it to objects in the ZMI. My product's `configure.zcml` contains:

```
<interface interface=".interfaces.IMarkerInterface" />
```

and, after reinstalling, the interface shows up in the list of available interfaces. But if I try to add it to an object in the ZMI I get a `ComponentLookupError`. What's missing?

Comment: Can you include the full traceback for the error?

Comment: I added a bogus <utility> that provides the interface in question, and it seems to work now, but I don't know why.

Answer (score 4):

It worked Ok for me.

I tested it in Plone 4.0.3

Created a package with paster:

`paster create -t plone bogus.interface`

With this interfaces.py file:

```
from zope.interface import Interface

class IBogusInterface(Interface):
    """ Marker bogus interface
    """
```

And this configure.zcml file:

```
<configure
    xmlns="http://namespaces.zope.org/zope"
    xmlns:five="http://namespaces.zope.org/five"
    xmlns:i18n="http://namespaces.zope.org/i18n"
    i18n_domain="bogus.interface">

  <five:registerPackage package="." initialize=".initialize" />

  <!-- -*- extra stuff goes here -*- -->
  <interface interface=".interfaces.IBogusInterface" />

</configure>
```

Are you sure you weren't missing anything?

Answer (score 3):

Also note that apparently, marker interfaces must be empty. They cannot contain attributes or methods - if they do, they won't show up in the ZMI.